# Angular 7 - Autoprefixer not working with CSS Grid

Tags: css, angular, grid, angular7, autoprefixer

I am trying to get Angular7 working nicely with the Autoprefixer. I'm specifically looking to get support on IE11. I've removed the "not" from "IE 9 - 11" in the browserlist file. I've also added

/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */
/* autoprefixer grid: on */

To the top of my _grid.scss file. Problem is grid items are still not getting any prefixes. Flexbox seems to work fine but not CSS grid. Is there any configuration I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had dependency issues. Ran

> npm audit fix

and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: How did you configure the autoprefixer to work with angular?

Comment: If you're working with angular 7+ autoprefixer should already be installed. So you just need to go into your browserslist file and target the relevant browsers. If you want to get it working with CSS grid you'll need to add come control comments to your css https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#does-autoprefixer-polyfill-grid-layout-for-ie